# Get emacs version from *within* emacs

Tags: linux, unix, emacs

Is it possible to determine the version of emacs you are running without using the `-version` option from the command line but rather from within emacs itself, anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type:

```
M-x emacs-version
```

That will display the emacs version in mini buffer. Example output I get from the above command:

```
GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.4) of 2013-04-09 on allspice, modified by Debian
```

Comment: It also returns the version string: `(find-function (quote emacs-version))`

Comment: thanks, i've got a few other newbie emacs questions coming that will be under the "emacs" tag